# How can hreflang be added to a Shopify website?

Tags: hreflang, shopify

I have these 3 directories for different countries. I can add an `hreflang` on WordPress, but I don't know where to implement it on my Shopify site.

`https://example.com` is for the USA

`https://nl.example.com` is for Netherlands

`https://example.com/en-de` is for Denmark

Can I set up this through the main domain (`https://example.com/`), or do I have to put this code in all the directories? And, where is this option?

Comment: It appears you have to add them to the `<head>` section of your theme in [theme.liquid](https://shopify.dev/themes/seo/hreflang). There are other methods, such as using Custom Fields, covered in [this](https://eastsideco.com/blog/everything-you-need-know-about-hreflang-and-shopify).

Comment: I check theme.liquid there I do not find my existing hreflang tag. If I go to via source code then I find my hreflang tag. I want to change this code, because there is some error.

Comment: `If I go to via source code then I find my hreflang tag`  In that case it seems you already added it _somewhere_. If not, then see if the second link above can help you identify where to change it.

Comment: https://bkinzstore.com/ there you will find this hreflang code, I want to remove them. Is there any other way to find hreflang code?

Comment: It appears that you might have a translation app installed since it can be translated to Dutch. The above linked to article states, `There are some Shopify apps that add Hreflang tags to your pages for you. Translation apps such as Weglot and Langify will automatically generate your Hreflang tags and add them to your pages.` So check if you have a translation app installed, and see if removing or disabling that removes the `hrefrelang` links as well.

Comment: I use the G-Translate app, maybe here is the problem. https://docs.google.com/document/d/13XWTc27jYgiI7Qfy8euTDQeL0oKceNo5VI1OLnPvDq4/edit?usp=sharing This app generates this code.

Comment: OK, try disabling that app and see if that resolves the issue for you (be sure to clear your browser's cache). If so, then add that to an answer below and accept it when you can so that it might be helpful to others in the future.

Comment: Finally I resolve it. Thanks for your valuable comments and I add an answer here.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a subdomain or subdirectory on the Shopify website, Shopify  automatically generates an `hreflang` tag on your store for that subdomain or subdirectory. You can't edit it through `theme.liquid`, the only option is you have to remove your subdirectory or subdomain from under: [Settings > Market](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/markets/managing-markets)